# Bloc Builder not rebuilding after navigation away and back to that page, Using Cubit

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-bloc

So I have a Cubit that is listening to an audio stream. When I first run load the page, the bloc builder rebuilds all of my UI as expected.

I then navigate away from the page, and try to resume activity. I am able to call a cubit function to trigger the hardware stream. My cubit is receiving that stream of data. I am able to print out logs from the hardware stream from within my cubit listener function, but when I call emit(NewState), the bloc builder doesn't rebuild.

Comment: Show the code..

Comment: Hard to say without code examples. Usually, when the BlocBuilders or BlocListeners are not triggered, it is because Dart is not able to tell whether the state changed. Are you using Equatable? If not, you may need to implement the `==` operator and `hashCode` of the state implementation.